# Can't godoc create documentation for packages within internal folder?

Tags: go, godoc

In a common **project structure** there are folders like:

/cmd

/internal

/pkg

however when executing `godoc`

No documentation is created for the packages within the *internal* folder:
[internal is missing between cmd and pkg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFSfu.png)

**Problem** is: there are functions within the package and they **need to be documented even for internal usage**. Is there any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For instance, https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/?m=all shows the
> documentation for all (not just the exported) declarations of package
> big.

As mentioned in this [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc#section-sourcefiles), using m=all parameter in URL will list internal packages. One caveat is that it includes all declarations including unexported declarations.

Comment: One trick is to include m=all to list internal package and navigate to the internal package. then you can remove the m=all flag to list only exported declarations in the internal package.

Comment: Thank both of you. It works.
I actually think the could have offered a cli flag for this functionality. This way it's a little obfuscated. There is also  `go doc -all` so ...